# 'System' is not a valid database edition in this version of SQL Server

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-cli

I'm trying to scale down an Azure SQL Database from `S0` to `Basic` but when I run:

```
 az sql db update -g MyResourceGroup -s MyServer -n MyDatabase --edition Basic --service-objective Basic
```

I receive the error:

```
(ProvisioningDisabled) 'System' is not a valid database edition in this version of SQL Server.
Code: ProvisioningDisabled
Message: 'System' is not a valid database edition in this version of SQL Server.
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are receiving that error then that database is associated with an Azure SQL Elastic Pool. The minimum service tier for a Basic Elastic Pool (DTU-model) is S0 as you can see in the [pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/azure-sql-database/elastic/) and as you can see on [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-pool-scale?view=azuresql-db#latency-of-changing-service-tier-or-rescaling-compute-size). You cannot have a basic tier database on a Basic Elastic Pool as the service tiers allowed for the type of pool are S0 to S12.